# Composer search does not find package hosted in drupal composer respository

Tags: drupal, composer-php

I'm trying to find what to call a particular module (In this case, [Google Simple Map](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_gmap)) so I can use Composer to add it to my Drupal project. I know its human readable name is Google Simple Map module.

But at the command line, running search, nothing for Google Simple Map is found:

```
$ composer search -N drupal | grep -i simple
drubb/drupal-simple                                   
drupalauth/simplesamlphp-module-drupalauth
```

Eventually, by trial and error, a long time later, Composer says something similar to "Are you trying to install drupal/simple_gmap? (closest match)"

My package installs fine then:

```
$ composer require drupal/simple_gmap
(success message here)
```

What was wrong with my original search syntax; how can I run search to find something like drupal/simple_gmap?

Answer (score 0):

Composer should be able to find these as long as the project in question has a release branch or tag and your `composer.json` file is set to look for the drupal respositories via:

```
  ...
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "composer",
      "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
    },
  ...
```

Each of the projects on Drupal.org does also mention an example command on the project page. Currently for **Simple Google Maps** latest stable release this is: https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_gmap/releases/3.0.1